# Is there a way to close nav dropdowns on screen resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bootstrap 4 navbar / dropdowns, in desktop they are opening with css animation / fade in. On mobile I have them opening with a seperate "toggle" button. Everything working as expected, however if I am in mobile and open the dropdowns and then resize my window screen the dropdowns remain open and it does not play well with the animation. Is there a way to have the dropdowns close when window resizes or gets to the desktop breakpoint?

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <div class="nav-title-flex-container">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=“home.html"
           id="navbar-drop-downs"
           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="underline"> Home</span>
        </a>
        <span class="openNav"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-nav-bottom"
         aria-labelledby="navbar-drop-downs">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href=“#”>Sub Page</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href=“#”>Sub page</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <div class="nav-title-flex-container">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="how-to-be-vocal.html"
       id="navbar-drop-downs"
       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="underline”>About </span>
    </a>
        <span class="openNav"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-nav-bottom"
         aria-labelledby="navbar-drop-downs">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href=“#”>Sub Page</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1199px) {
  .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    animation: fadein .7s;
  }
}
```

jquery: (toggling dropdowns / mobile)

```
  $openNavToggle.on('click', function () {
  $(this).parent().next('.dropdown-menu-nav-bottom').toggleClass('show');
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right--active');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using media queries?

Comment: jQuery has a `.resize()` event listener you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of jQuery's `resize` event handler.

You'll also want to make sure you're removing those classes, not just toggling them - or else the nav could *appear* when resizing;

```
$openNavToggle.resize(function () {
  $(this).parent().next('.dropdown-menu-nav-bottom').removeClass('show');
  $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-right--active');
})
```

Also, you can make use of a *kinda* debounce to make sure the resize function only takes affect at the end of the resize, like so:

```
let resizeEvent;
$openNavToggle.resize(function () {
  clearTimeout(resizeEvent);
  resizeEvent = setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).parent().next('.dropdown-menu-nav-bottom').removeClass('show');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-right--active');
  }, 300);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for resize event on the window:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', (e)=>{
    // ... call your show/hide here.
    // ... and/or check new width and do logic on this.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the [window resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

Then check if the size has the required dimensions, and act accordingly.

For performance benefits a common method used in conjunction is the debounce method: https://gomakethings.com/debouncing-your-javascript-events/

Comment: Why a -1? :\ At least leave a comment with some feedback?

Comment: I didn't give you a downvote but maybe it's because of "window resize method". That's an event but it's probably just a "typo". Giving you the upvote to have it even as the downvoter most likely won't come back here again.

Comment: Ah oké. Typo indeed, I meant the window resize event method. But method would be poor wording in this case. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hide function:

```
function hide() {
   $(this).parent().next('.dropdown-menu-nav-bottom').toggleClass('hide');
   $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-angle-right--inactive');
}
```

Bind it to resize event:

```
$(window).resize(hide);
```